# Mutate several functions pairwise in a generalizable way in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have two vectors of names in my database (say one represent a component and second represent values) and I'm trying to develop a function that would create new columns based  of the two vectors in a generalizable way I.E. something along the line of :

```
#vector components and values contain column names from the dataset

creaYK<-function(data,Input="A",Components=c("A", "B", "C"),Values=c("D", "E", "F")){
    
 for(i in 1:length(Values)){
      data<-data%>%mutate(new_i = sum(Values[i],Components[i]))
              
    }
}
```

my problem is that I need my arguments "vec1" and "vec2" to be modifiable in content and length and the calculation to be performed pairwise (each element of vec1 being summed to the corresponding in vec2). I have tried something with `across()` but it failed.

here is the desired output :

```
vec1<-c("A","B","C")
vec2<-c("D","E","F")

data<-tibble(A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,E=5,F=6)

# what I want is a function returning :

# function(data,vec1,vec2)

tibble(A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,E=5,F=6,ad=5,be=7,cf=9)
```

But the code above only creates one new column,and my attempts with mutate were also unsuccessful

Moreover, the name of indicators are not structured in the same way as the name of the value used

Comment: I also tried to figure something with map2 but was unsuccessfull, the error withmy current code is `Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: Why use `mutate` in a for-loop? Unless you are looping through dataframes, you should not use mutate in a for-loop

Comment: have you tried `cumsum()`

Comment: `data %>%mutate(ad = A + D, be = B + E, cf = C + F)` is what you are looking for

Comment: I am looping trough dataframesun fortunately , `data %>%mutate(ad = A + D, be = B + E, cf = C + F)` is the result needed but I need to be able to do it without calling the variable names inside of mutate (user wants to be able to change the definition of "ad" directly from a function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you might want

```
library(dplyr)

a <- c(2,5,6)
b <- c(4,9,6)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

tribble <- function(data,vec1,vec2){
  sum_v1v2 <- vec1+vec2
  a <- data %>% mutate(Sum_of_components = sum_v1v2)
}
b <- tribble(df,a,b)
```

Output:

```
  a b Sum_of_components
1 2 4                 6
2 5 9                14
3 6 6                12
```

Comment: that's the Idea but vec 1 and vec 2 are vectors of columns names in a DF that I must be able to change and not actual numeric vectors